# Javascript not working properly in template

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem linking a javascript file to my template. I'm using the standard tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{template_root}site_script.js"></script>
```

Where {template_root} is the location of my template files. I have tested this URL (stored as a global variable} for accuracy. For testing purposes, my site_script.js file looks like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
});
```

However no dialogue is popping up. I took a look in the console log and it says "**ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $**". I'm really at a loss here and I would appreciate if someone can show me where I may have made an error?

I'm not sure if this is necessary or helpful, but here is my index template file for context:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- Force proper sizing -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Styles that require EE Template Tag Parsing -->
        {exp:channel:entries channel="preferences"}<style type="text/css">
            body {background-image:url('{background_image}');}
            .color {color: #{primary_highlight_color};}
            .color_bg {background-color: #{primary_highlight_color};}
            .nav_circle {background-color:rgba(0,0,0,{nav_opacity_unselected});}
        </style>
        {/exp:channel:entries}

        <!-- TypeKit Scripts  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/yjd5vpe.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

        {exp:channel:entries channel="preferences"}
            <title>{title}</title>
        {/exp:channel:entries}

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{stylesheet='website/global'}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{stylesheet='website/web'}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{stylesheet='website/mobile'}" />

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="{template_root}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        {!--
        <!-- Development Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="global.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="web.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="mobile.css" />
        <!-- Development Javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="site_script.js"></script>
        --}



    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- masthead Snippet-->
            <div class="masthead">
                {exp:channel:entries channel="preferences"}<div class="logo"><img src="{dandelion_logo}" /></div>{/exp:channel:entries}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="contact"}<div class="nav_social_icons" />test</div>{/exp:channel:entries}
                <div id="navigation">

                    <div class="nav_item">
                        <div class="nav_circle">
                            {exp:channel:entries channel="Cart"}<img src="{cart_icon}" class="nav_icon_cart" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav_title">
                            {title}
                        </div>{/exp:channel:entries}
                    </div> <!-- Cart .nav_item -->      

                    <div class="nav_item">
                        <div class="nav_circle">
                            {exp:channel:entries channel="Shop"}<img src="{shop_icon}" class="nav_icon_shop" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav_title">
                            {title}
                        </div>{/exp:channel:entries}
                    </div> <!-- Shop .nav_item -->    

                    <div class="nav_item">
                        <div class="nav_circle">
                            {exp:channel:entries channel="events"}<img src="{events_icon}" class="nav_icon_events" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav_title">
                            {title}
                        </div>{/exp:channel:entries}
                    </div> <!-- Events .nav_item -->  

                    <div class="nav_item">
                        <div class="nav_circle">
                            {exp:channel:entries channel="contact"}<img src="{contact_icon}" class="nav_icon_contact" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav_title">
                            {title}
                        </div>{/exp:channel:entries}
                    </div> <!-- Contact .nav_item -->  

                    <div class="nav_item">
                        <div class="nav_circle">
                            {exp:channel:entries channel="home"}<img src="{home_icon}" class="nav_icon_home" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav_title">
                            {title}
                        </div>{/exp:channel:entries}
                    </div> <!-- Home .nav_item -->

                </div> <!-- #navigation -->
            </div> <!-- .masthead -->






    WRAPPER BOTTOM<br />
        </div> <!-- .wrapper -->

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{template_root}site_script.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JQuery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{template_root}bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not actually EE-related - your scripts are in the wrong order. You're calling your `site_script` before you've loaded jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{template_root}site_script.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Reverse the order of those and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't notice this.